# C#, ArrayList Property to List field

Tags: c#, properties, arraylist, field, ilist

I have the following Field:

```
private IList<Modulo> modulos;
```

and the following Property:

```
    public virtual ArrayList XmlModulos
    {
        get
        {
            if (modulos == null) return new ArrayList();
            var aux = new ArrayList();
            foreach (Modulo m in modulos)
                aux.Add(m);
            return aux;
        }
        set
        {
            modulos = new List<Modulo>();
            foreach (object o in value)
                modulos.Add((Modulo)o);
        }

    }
```

The get works perfectly, as I have another direct property that is used for different purposes. But the set is not working, as when I use this property it doesn't update anything. The debug says that the Property is an empty ArrayList (count 0) and the field stays in null. Any Idea why this is not working? any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: You probably shouldn’t use the obsolete `ArrayList` from C# 1.0. Use a generic collection for proper type safety. Consider, for example, declaring the property as `IEnumerable<Modulo>`.

Comment: I'm Using ArrayList because it's the collection most widely used for Xml Serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's going on here, you must realize that .NET properties are simply a convenient way to represent two separate **methods**, one for getting and another for setting.

That is, they basically map these operations:

```
ArrayList m = obj.XmlModulos;

obj.XmlModulos = new ArrayList();
```

to code that really more closely resembles this:

```
ArrayList m = obj.get_XmlModulos();

obj.set_XmlModulos(new ArrayList());
```

OK, so with this in mind, let's consider what you're trying to do (this is based on a comment to [Timwi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540204/c-arraylist-property-to-list-field/3540221#3540221)):

```
obj.XmlModulos.Add(new Modulo());
```

What this is *really* doing is:

```
obj.get_XmlModulos().Add(new Modulo());
```

Considering your `get` accessor creates **a new `ArrayList`**, you're never going to be able to add a `Modulo` to your collection in this way. The only way you could do it would be this:

```
ArrayList m = obj.XmlModulos;

m.Add(new Modulo());

obj.XmlModulos = m;
```

**HOWEVER**, this is **a very inefficient way to implement your `get` and `set` accessors**. Creating a new `ArrayList` on every `get` and populating it with the current members of `modulos` is costly. So is enumerating over any value passed to `set` and copying each to `modulos`.

If anything, this class design is backwards (really, most developers would advise steering clear of the `ArrayList` type altogether these days; but if you insist, that's your call). You are storing an `IList<Modulo>` (which provides type safety) internally but exposing an `ArrayList` (which does *not*) externally; what this means is that someone could easily try to add some random object of non-`Modulo` type to your list and you would get an `InvalidCastException`. Code that tries to do this really ought not to compile at all; that's the whole point of generics.

OK, I've said enough. What do I suggest? Have just one collection belonging to this class. Decide what functionality you *actually* want to provide, and expose just that functionality. Don't do this expensive copying back and forth between two collections.

For example, if you truly need an `ArrayList`, but you only need to enable client code to add and remove elements to/from it, then implement it like this:

```
private ArrayList modulos;

public void AddModulo(Modulo m)
{
    modulos.Add(m);
}

public bool RemoveModulo(Modulo m)
{
    return modulos.Remove(m);
}
```

This way, even though you're using a non-generic `ArrayList` internally (if you have good reasons for this), you're still getting the effective type safety of an `IList<T>` by only allowing client code to add and remove items of the `Modulo` type.

This could be very different from the solution that actually makes sense for you. Let it hopefully steer you in the right direction, at least.

Comment: The reason I'm using an IList and an ArrayList is because I'm trying to combine NHibernate with Xml Serialization, as Nhibernate needs ILists to work and the most reliable examples of Xml Serialization I found used ArrayLists. In the end I decided to use two different properties and make the change manually as needed. There has to be a simpler way to do this but time was starting to be an issue. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue; I copied your code and then executed this line:

```
XmlModulos = new ArrayList { new Modulo() };
```

After this, both the debugger and `Console.WriteLine` report both `modulos.Count` and `XmlModulos.Count` as `1`.

Therefore, the error lies in some other code that you haven’t shown us.

Comment: But If I then do something like this: XmlModulos.Add(New Modulo()); the Count will still be one

Comment: Yes, obviously. Every time you access `XmlModulos` you are creating a new list. Your `Add` modifies that new list, not the one in `modulos`.